# getspans(start, end, class) how it is working for ForegroundColorSpan

Tags: java, android, html, spanned

I have a text where I set ForegroundColorSpan for some words

```
documentText.getText().setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);
```

next step: I need to find my spanned text and clean it(only for text which I spanned).I try to do:

```
ForegroundColorSpan[] ColorSpan = documentText.getText().getSpans(0,documentText.length(),ForegroundColorSpan.class);
    int length = ColorSpan.length;
    for (ForegroundColorSpan span : ColorSpan) {
        int Start= documentText.getText().getSpanStart(span);
        int End= documentText.getText().getSpanEnd(span);
        int ForegroundColor = span.getForegroundColor();
        if (ForegroundColor == Color.BLUE) {
            for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
                documentText.getText().removeSpan(ColorSpan[i]);
        }
```

It is not working.
Also I have question about `int length = ColorSpan.length;`
Why when I remove or add any symbol(s) length was increased?

Comment: try `TextUtils#dumpSpans` before and after calling your code